# How to use complete space while printing lable using c#

Tags: c#, printing, label

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzf6T.png)I want to print data to a label using c# application. I created the application for the same purpose. Since there is only limited space in the label, I need to use the full white space available.

Here I have attached the two pictures of the data showing in the window and in the print preview. In print preview it is shown that white space from both sides are gone.But after printing in the label there is space at both ends.

Is there any way to use the complete space.

The Code I used for the same is below.

```
    public PrintPreviewExt()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern long BitBlt(IntPtr hdcDest, int nXDest, int nYDest, int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hdcSrc, int nXSrc, int nYSrc, int dwRop);
    private Bitmap memoryImage;

    private void PrintScreen()
    {
        Graphics mygraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
        Size s = this.Size;
        memoryImage = new Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height, mygraphics);
        Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryImage);
        IntPtr dc1 = mygraphics.GetHdc();
        IntPtr dc2 = memoryGraphics.GetHdc();
        BitBlt(dc2, 0, 0, this.ClientRectangle.Width, this.ClientRectangle.Height, dc1, 0, 0, 13369376);
        mygraphics.ReleaseHdc(dc1);
        memoryGraphics.ReleaseHdc(dc2);
    }
    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(memoryImage, 0, 0);
    }

    private void print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        print.Visible = false;
        PrintScreen();
        printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
        this.Hide();
    }
```

Comment: Where are the attached pictures?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/dzf6T.png